# How to make array in JSON?

Tags: php, json

Here, I want to a make array of requests in the below code so, I want to store multiple images in that requests until the for loops terminate.

How could I do that ?

```
 for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
 {         
   $imageName = __DIR__.'/uploads/'.$i.time().'.png';
   $data= file_get_contents($imageName);
   $base64 = base64_encode($data);
   $type = 'TEXT_DETECTION';
   $request_json[] = '
   {
       "requests": [
         {
            "image": {
                "content":"' . $base64 . '"
          },
            "features": [
               {
                 "type": "' . $type . '",
                   "maxResults": 200
                }
             ]
          }
            ]
        }';
 }
```

Please Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
 {         
   $imageName = __DIR__.'/uploads/'.$i.time().'.png';
   $data= file_get_contents($imageName);
   $base64 = base64_encode($data);
   $request_json['requests'][] = ['image' => ['content' => $base64],
           'features' => ['type' => 'TEXT_DETECTION', 'maxResults' => 200]
   ];
 }

 echo json_encode($request_json);
```

Comment: Great! Also $type is not dynamic so you can put its value directly... no need to put in one extra variable. Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, you are right but I need this value at some places. But it's fine. Thanks